# Why is Helium 4 so stable?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy, elements

I've been looking at stuff to do with binding energies and was wondering why Helium 4 is so stable. The fact everything up to carbon is less stable seems a bit odd. Is there a reason for this or another, that's how the universe works?

Comment: To what would it decay to? The real question is why Fe-56 is so stable...

Comment: Not mainly decay. More the fact that you need to put in energy to fuse it to anything before carbon

Comment: "you need to put in energy to fuse it to anything" right... then what powers stars again?

Comment: If you consider the shell model with the spin-orbit interaction, then you can easily show that the first magic number is 2 when you fill up the level regarding intrinsic properties of the particles (spin). After this level, there is a big gap in term of single-particle energy.

Comment: Other doubly magic (ie nuclei with closed shells of both protons and neutrons) also exhibit extra binding (stability) with O-16, Ca-40, Ca-48 and Pb-208 being the most prominent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one regards the nucleus as a potential well for nucleons, there is one lowest level. It can contain:

- a spin-up proton
- a spin-down proton
- a spin-up neutron
- a spin-down neutron

Then that lowest level is full. Any additional nucleons can only find a place in levels with higher kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as Pieter mentions being fermions with Pauli exclusion you can get a spin up and a a spin down in the same ground state for both n and p. Like in atomic physics you can put 2 electrons in the s orbital.
In addition a geometric effect that 4 particles can be arranged in a tetrahedron shape with each ball touching the other 3 giving a very high binding energy per nucleon compared to say 3 nucleons. So that may explain why He4 is ejected in preference to He3 or He2 or H3 or dineutron or often even in preference to a single proton or neutron.